# Search for specific part of csv file name and append to new csv file(PHP)

Tags: php, csv

I was wondering if there was a way to find specific parts of a csv filename and use that specific part when writing a new file (another CSV). I have some codes below:

```
$files = glob("C:\readonly\csvs\%.csv");
$filename = "C:\newcsvs\Dated_File.csv";

$newFile = fopen($filename, "w");
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            fputcsv($newFile, [$data[0], $data[1]]);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($newFile);
}
```

So let's say for example I have a CSV with the file name of `Johnson_report[2019-02-05]-[2019-02-15].csv` and I wanted to take the end portion [2019-02-15] and append that to the new CSV when it's written how would I go about doing that? Specifically, each new CSV that I would make would have to take whatever the file's specific ending characters (they will always end in a specific date range) and use that ending date in the name of the new CSV. I understand that glob can find specific patterns but how would I use it in this manner?

Comment: You probably want to use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on the file names to grab the date parts.

Comment: alright i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeto, preg_match & the renaming functions were the answers. Used preg_match to find the dates, then appended each match to the file name with the rename function after the file was closed while within the foreach loop.